# How to install LocalDB 2017 along with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, localdb

I installed Visual Studio 2017 enterprise version 15.5.7. and SQL Server data tools SQL Server Data Tools   15.1.61710.120.
I get following version of `MSSQLLocalDB`

Version:            13.1.4001.0

How can I get version 14.0?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlmeditation/2018/03/05/functions-like-string_agg-concat_ws-trim-appear-to-break-in-visual-studio-2017-database-projects/

Comment: That worked. thx. I had to create a localdb before I could see installed versions.

Answer (score 1):

I had to also go to Tools, Options, Database Tools, Data Connections and change the SQL Server Instance name to the instance running v14.